# Apache2+PHP fopen() permisson

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, php5, debian-squeeze, fopen

**Intro:**

I am sorry to be asking for help when there's loads of that on the internet, however I'm not Linux savvy.

**Problem:**

I've installed apache2 and PHP5 under debian, and uses of PHP fopen() function produce typical:

Warning: fopen(/some/where/some.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /some/file/location/of/script/index.php on some line

**Hoped response:**

I would be very grateful if anyone could kindly supply me with a secure/minimum required solution to make it work, and even better if that would be explained as well.

**Weak assumption:**

It is extremely likely that some folders or configurations require correct permissions set, however I am in a dark forest when it comes to that.

**Notes:**

- Apache is compiled and installed from source. PHP is compiled and
- installed from source, without default php.ini
- Above should be considered with me not being Linux savvy and not getting permissions.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to be nothing to do with your Apache/PHP setup however you've provided **no information** about how these are configured. Most likely the user the PHP script is running a does not have permission to open the files. Without knowing how it's configured I can't tell you how to get this information (`ps auxwww | grep php` *might* show the user). Nor have you told us what the permissions / ownership on the files are (`chmod a+wr filename.txt` makes a filereadable/writeable by any user - but that seriously compromises security).

How you make your files accessible and secure depends on your security policy but knowing nothing about the machine / it's purpose nor how it is configured would make it impossible even with your security policy.

A further consideration is that storing data in flat files, accessed directly via PHP is almost always a *very* bad idea. It does not scale and can lead to deadlocks and race conditions.

Comment: If you want the machine to be secure then you need the skills to manage / configure it.